# What is the default accuracy in the Android location service?

Tags: android, gps, location

If we don't specify the accuracy for the location service in android, what is the default we have to use? 
And is it required to specify both permissions?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify accuracy you'll just get the best one available.  So it depends on whether it's using AGPS or GPS and if the GPS has a good, solid fix.